# What are these cryptic numbers? I've seen them popping up sporadically during my years in IT, but I never asked what they were

Tags: windows-10

I believe I've stumbled upon something like this one time when I opened an exe file with an editor? (Couldn't recall exactly how to reproduce those) I've seen them popping up sporadically during my years in IT, but I never asked what they are. Does anyone know what they are and what we can use them for? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: They are hexadecimal numbers.  Did you do any work on this at all

Comment: Your editor behaves like HexEdit and shows each bytes of your file as an hexadecimal numbers (in white). You see in green the address of the first byte of the line in hexadecimal too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what they are?

They are are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (Base 16) representations of [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (Base 2) data. Binary sequences (`010101....`) are how all data on a computer is stored (text files, images, executables, etc.).

> What we can use them for?

Hexadecimal (`0F 0F 0F....`) is often used to represent binary data because it is (arguably) easier to work with, assuming someone wishes to read or edit that data for some reason. For instance, 255 in binary is `11111111` but written in hexadecimal is just `FF`.

As one practical example of how this can be used, software crackers may examine or edit raw file data to defeat security measures put in place by a software publisher.